# Совместное использование таблиц MyISAM и InnoDB

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли совместно использовать в БД и таблицы типа MyISAM и InnoDB? Не будет ли в связи с этим каких-либо проблем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Учтите, что на MyISAM не распространяются транзакции и проверки внешних ключей.

Пожелания из интернетов:

- Не делать совместных запросов на
     изменение. Лучше делать запрос к
     каждому виду таблицы по отдельности.
- Типы связанных полей должны быть
     полностью одинаковыми.
- Для бекапа
     использовать сохранения в дамп.
     Никакого копирования файлов — чревато
     порчей данных.

Comment: Спасибо, только не поняла про типы связанных полей - это про внешние ключи?

Comment: @Mariya ага

Comment: а вот по поводу совместных запросов - это только на изменение? Просто селект сразу из нескольких таблиц разных типов не приведет ни к чему плохому?

Comment: @Mariya по идее нет :-)

Answer (score 1):

Кроме того, при наличии в базе данных хотя бы одной таблицы MyISAM теряется основная прелесть InnoDB: локи по строкам, а не по таблицам. Что значительно уменьшает производительность БД в целом.

Если для Вас скорость работы не критична и вы можете позволить себе делать локи таблиц при чтении, тогда только вышеперечисленные последствия. Если у вас большая нагрузка, стоит задуматься, что InnoDB блокирует только строку, а MyISAM - всю таблицу. Их микс приводит к потере этот доработки по InnoDB.

Comment: А не подскажете, что считается большой нагрузкой? У нас сейчас нагрузка 8-10 000 человек в день. Вся нагрузка - на чтение.

Comment: но в будущем надеются увеличить посещаемость до 100 000 человек в день.

Comment: просто структура хранения данных в БД сложная, поэтому в некот. случаях без транзакций, при внесении информации через админку не обойтись. Изначально вся БД была MyISAM, и только для сохранения целостности данных при сбое, например, во время внесения данных, я решила конвертировать часть таблиц в InnoDB, чтобы можно было использовать транзакции.

Comment: Получается, что если у нас почти не будет нагрузки на внесение информации, а транзакции нужны только там, то не получится потерь в скорости при наличии в БД таблиц 2-х типов?